# Where is documentation of switch options for apache2ctl command?

Tags: apache, manpage

I can run `apache2ctl -S` on my debian box and it outputs information about the virtual hosts on the server and other information.

However, when I issue `man apache2ctl` on my debian box, I don't see any documentation for the the `-S` switch or any other switches for that matter. Where can I find this documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page states that apachectl acts either as passthrough frontend script for httpd binary itself or as service control script for starting, stopping, reloading.
In turn You can / should consult the man page for httpd to find the information about such switches.

Comment: Thanks. And on debian the binary is called `apache2` not `httpd`. I notice that some switches that work for `apache2ctl` dont work with `apache2`. For example, `apache2 -S` switch throws an error. So Debian apparently forces you to use the `apache2ctl` command wrapper.

Comment: Indeed it does something more than plain call to apache2 binary, that's probably the reason this passtrough exists. But on default Ubuntu 19.04 setups it does not more then sourcing /etc/apache2/envvars that is really relevant for running the binary. So You could do the same. If You are using different confdir it sets the -d argument for apache2 in addition.